# How to call a variable in another method to your main method

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I'm having a bit of trouble trying to call a variable (firstName) from another method to my main. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter full name: ");
      String fullName = reader.nextLine();
      System.out.print("Enter graduation year: ");
      int gradYear = reader.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Greetings, " + firstName + ", your initials are ");
   }
   
   public static void getFirstName(String fullName) {
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
      String firstName = fullName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + fullName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
   }
}
```

Comment: Change `void` to `String` on line 12 and add `return firstName;` after line 14.  Also replace `firstName` with `getFirstName(fullName);` where you want to call your method.

Answer (score 0):

You can return that value from a method and assign to a variable.

Let me show you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter full name: ");
    String fullName = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter graduation year: ");
    int gradYear = reader.nextInt();

    String firstName = getFirstName(fullName);
    System.out.print("Greetings, " + firstName + ", your initials are ");
}

public static String getFirstName(String fullName) {
    // Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstName = fullName.substring(1).toLowerCase(); // assuming first letter is the initials; best would be to substring by space or similar
    return firstName;
}
```

Comment: Also how does this code convert `fullname` to `firstname`?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Sorry, my bad. I did not change the content of that `getFirstName()` method other than introducing a return as the main question was about how to return a value. Now I have updated the answer by commenting out it, so that he understands it.

Comment: @ScaryWombat `Also how does this code convert fullname to firstname?` - that is not a concern for him yet it seems, so I did not want to complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

First of note that after using nextInt() the following nextLine() won't work.

I guess, this is what you are trying to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter full name: ");
    String fullName = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter graduation year: ");
    int gradYear = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Greetings, " + getFirstName(fullName) + " your initial is, " + getInitial(fullName));
    reader.close();
}

private static String getInitial(String fullName) {
    return fullName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
}

public static String getFirstName(String fullName) {
    return fullName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: `First of note that after using nextInt() the following nextLine() won't work.` - This is not correct.

Comment: nextInt() won't call for the next line after it reads the integer. So, whenever you use the nextLine() in your code. It'll assume that this is just the 'nextInt()' new line and will not execute your line of code.